# Can I use OR (||) operator on two different data types in Angular4?

Tags: angular, logical-operators

I have two return types which are string(x) and boolean(y)

I am trying to use (DisplayIcon) = x || y but seems like I am not getting Icon enabled for the cases which have either of values present in those two.

So, Can I use || on two different return types at all? If so, hwo can I accomplish this?

Please advise

Comment: How is it not working? Please provide an [mcve], I recommend you use https://stackblitz.com

Comment: Could you please give your html code. Is it your return problem or html view problem I couldn't understand properly. If it is your ts method return issue then you can do as follows getData(value:number):string|boolean{ return value==1 ? "Test": false; }